# Need help segmentation fault in ruby 1.9.2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I'm try using mysql2 gem in my rails 3 application. When I using whenever gem and write crontab. I got this problem in cron's log:

> /home/mine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@myrailsapplication/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]

I have no clue, why segmentation fault for ruby 1.8.7 when I using ruby 1.9.2..

Please help me, what is this error mean and how to fix it?

thanks..

Comment: I am getting the same when running any rake commands recently. I don't know what I have changed to my environment :( Did you find a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu and installed `rspec` using `apt-get` (e.g. `sudo apt-get install librspec-ruby1.8`) you will run into this issue. You need to remove `rspec` as a system install and instead install it with `rvm` (or whatever other `ruby` manager you are using):

```
sudo apt-get remove librspec-ruby1.8
rvm gem install rspec-rails
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly why this is happening without any code, but in general this would indicate that the environment in which your cron job is running isn't setup properly. I'm going to guess that your cron job is using your system default ruby.